# Slow query using a negative numeric search parameter

Tags: sql-server-ce

If I execute a query in SQL Server CE with an integer query parameter specified as a negative number, it executes 10 times slower than if that same parameter was a positive number.

For example:

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM table_x WHERE param = 1
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM table_x WHERE param = -1
```

Query 1 will execute 10X faster than Query 2.

Does anyone know why this might be true?

I am using SQL Server Compact 4.0.  My application is written in C++ and uses the ATL OLEDB API to manipulate the DB.

Comment: Try with proper paremeterized sql

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "proper parameterized sql."

Comment: in .NET, using SQL like "SELECT * FROm Table where param = @p1" and the using DbParameter object to add to DbCommand with proper SqlType defined

Comment: I am using C++/OLE DB and I don't believe that API offers something similar.